Swift AVAsset naturalSize error: Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation
let vidWidth = asset?.naturalSize()?.width
let vidHeight = asset?.naturalSize()?.height

I'm getting:
Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation

How to do this correctly?
What I've tried:
let vidWidth: CGFloat = asset?.naturalSize()?.width
let vidHeight: CGFloat = asset?.naturalSize()?.height

but I'm still getting the same error

As stated Here naturalSize is deprectaed from AVAsset  , you need to use load(.naturalSize) of AVAssetTrack
Task {
    do {
        let asset:AVAsset? = nil // For testing purposes
        let size = try await asset?.load(.tracks).first?.load(.naturalSize)
        print(size?.width)
        print(size?.height)
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

